# How to fix github oauth token for invalid characters: "__TOKEN__"?

Tags: php, laravel, git, github

when I want to download new laravel application then the error occur:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel App
```

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters: "**TOKEN**"

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

Comment: It might be the issue with your `github` credential? Please make sure it is correct.

Comment: No it's not credential issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution?